# What's the English name for this three-wheeled manual pedal vehicle in China?

Tags: nouns

What's the English name of this transport vehicle commonly used in China?

[image: Three-wheeled manual pedal vehicle in China]

Note this vehicle is commonly used to transport items, such vegetables by sellers, a TV bought from a shop, etc.

If no English word exists, what's the best approximation?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not aware of a name, I've seen one only once in the UK and I think the guy made that himself. I'd call it an *extended platform tricycle*.

Comment: I found "freight bicycle" on wikipedia.

Comment: I'd call it a cargo bike if I had to describe it to somebody who hadn't seen it. It's three-wheel, but that's less important than its function. If my addressee could see it, I'd call it a tricycle truck; but without some visual information that's not a good description.

Comment: Is there even a Chinese name for these? I've always just called them 三轮车, but that's just any tricycle, not just the flatbed ones that you see everywhere in Chinese.

Comment: Here's a website in Taiwan that calls a similar contraption (with the cargo space in front) a "carrier bike".  It's described in Chinese as a bicycle with a large box.  Link:  http://e-info.org.tw/node/14434

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I personally prefer "flatbed tricycle" or "freight tricycle".  This vehicle is primarily designed to transport goods, not people (though people can ride on it).

Comment: What is"manual" about this?

Comment: @Jim it's the handlebars.  lol

Answer (score 9):

That's called a "[cycle rickshaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_rickshaw)," or more commonly a "pedicab" when it's used to transport people rather than cargo.

Comment: I don't think it can be a "rickshaw" if it's *not* a passenger vehicle though

Comment: @Rupe You need a better argument than 'I don't think' when Jadasc's linked Wikipedia article has a picture of a flatbed trike claimed to show 'A cycle rickshaw carrying shoe boxes in Agra'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Apologies, that wasn't supposed to sound so dogmatic. It's more that I think people tend to think of passenger vehicles when they hear "rickshaws" so it's better to use a word like *freight* or *cargo* in the name of the thing in the picture. I like your "flatbed trike" too.

Comment: @Edwin That picture does go against the main grain of the article, though. From a quick scan, it looks like pretty much all the text (and certainly all the other images) in the article is quite specifically about rickshaws intended to transport passengers. That picture is the only thing that relates to this type of trike at all.

Comment: I think every Asian country has a different (English) term for the passenger type.  Lonely Planet put out a picture book about them once.

Comment: Last I looked Agra was not in mainland China.

Comment: [Here](http://www.loupiote.com/sets/72157622834302637.shtml) are pictures of all the rickshaws in the world. _Well, that might be a slight exaggeration._ The industrious photographer says: 'Cycle rickshaws are human-powered tricycles mostly used as taxi[s] or to transport freight around cities in [A]sia.­'

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Google Translate's version of the Chinese 非机动货运三轮车, which is *Non-Motorized Freight Tricycle*. Or, just *Freight Tricycle* or *Cargo Tricycle*, since we don't normally think of a tricycle as motorized.

The Chinese term appears, for example, in this [law link](http://law.china.cn/features/2014-05/07/content_6890774.htm) regarding licencing of 非机动货运三轮车 (Fēi jīdòng huòyùn sānlúnchē) drivers and a system of demerit points (in [Cangzhou, Hebei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cangzhou)).

Comment: _Freight/cargo tricycle_ at least definitely includes this type of trike, though it may also refer to other types (Google imaging 货运三轮车 gives lots if pictures of trikes with various compartment-like storage units, and not so many flatbed ones). I suppose a compromise between accuracy and unwieldiness would be _flatbed freight/cargo trike_.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a "rickshaw van" in India.